# AWS pem key not working

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

Along before I Login/used AWS instance by access it using SSH and .pem key.

Now after many days I used that same .pem key to login the instance using SSH but it throws error. This may be due to some permission.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/abc.pem user@example.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0664 for '/.ssh/abc.pem' are too open.

It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /.ssh/abc.pem
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can Some body explain me why it is so?

Comment: Incase you missed it `Permissions 0664 for '/.ssh/abc.pem' are too open.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do "chmod 400 abc.pem". I checked my A.pem, it seems the permission is only -r--------.

Comment: Yeah thanks!!  400 did the work